# Allowing the user to submit images within a Cocoa application

Tags: image, core-data, interface-builder

How do you set up an object in interface builder that will allow the user to submit an image (like when editing a vCard in Address Book) and save it to the corresponding entry in the database being managed by Core Data?

**Solution**

Use an `NSImageView` object.  On the first panel of the inspector for the object, you'll see a checkbox marked `Editable` that will allow you to decide whether to accept submissions or just display output.

Bindings for the object are as follows:

```
-> Value.Data
    Bind to: Source Entity
    Controller Key: selection
    Model Key Path: Name of the attribute within the entity storing the image data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `NSImageView` will do the trick. Link to reference: [link text](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If I remember well this component is available on Interface Builder..

Comment: Ah, hadn't seen the `Editable` checkbox on the inspector for that before.  Thanks!

For future reference should anyone else have the same question, bindings to the `NSImageView` object work as follows:

    -> Value.Data
        Bind to: Source Entity
        Controller Key: selection
        Model Key Path: Name of the attribute which stores the image data

Comment: Ach, forgot that you can't format replies.  Will add to the original post.  Thanks again!